# Adding hyperlinks inside SSRS text paragraph

Tags: reporting-services, hyperlink, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a paragraph of text and I need to add two hyperlinks inside the text.
We can't break this out and I can't seem to figure what commands to add.

Example:

full text:

'It is a period of civil wars in the galaxy. A brave alliance of underground freedom fighters has challenged the tyranny and oppression of the awesome GALACTIC EMPIRE. --> ***should be a hyperlink to galactic@empire.com***

Striking from a fortress hidden among the billion stars of the galaxy, rebel spaceships have won their first victory in a battle with the powerful Imperial Starfleet. The EMPIRE fears that another defeat could bring a thousand more solar systems into the rebellion, and Imperial control over the galaxy would be lost forever.

To crush the rebellion once and for all, the EMPIRE ***- should click to empire.com*** is constructing a sinister new battle station. Powerful enough to destroy an entire planet, its completion spells certain doom for the champions of freedom.'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Placeholders in the text box to separate the text and add Actions to the two placeholders that you need to add links to.

Create the text box.

Click in the text box to type and then right click Create Placeholder.

Click on the Expression (Fx) button of the Value box. Add your text inside quotes after an equals sign.

`="Your text here"`

Click OK to get back to the properties. Click on HTML to allow HTML code and OK again.

Click in the text box again two or three times to get the cursor to the right of your last text placeholder, then right-click and Add Placeholder again.

Add the text again. `="Empire"` Ok. Click on HTML. Now go to the Action and add the email link  `mailTo:galactic@empire.com`.

Repeat the steps for the other text and link.

You'll end up with a single text box with multiple text placeholders. You can add color for the links if desired.

[image]

When it runs, it will show the text with links.

[image]

You can use the < br > tags to separate the paragraphs.

Comment: I also fixed some of the biased text that some traitor sneaked in to give the rebels some sympathy. The red in the pic indicates that I was hovering over EMPIRE with the link showing in the Status Bar at the bottom.

Comment: this is great, my email link works but the second link the one that is just a webpage doesn't work. when i wrote google.com lets say into the url under action it isn't clicking - is that because its inside SSRS set up or did i miss a tag? thank you again.

Comment: @one more question is there a way to add if then logic, iff(scenario = ABC, "print some string ... finish string with the hyperlink ... else string with the hyperlink again. I can't seem to stop an iff statement mid expression to add hyperlink element.

Comment: @YelizavetaYR - i was using `="http://Empire.com"` to link to the our glorious leaders website.

Comment: @YelizavetaYR - for the logic, I would have separate placeholders for each. `=IIF(scenario = ABC, "print some string", "")` then a second with `=IIF(scenario <> ABC, "otehr string", "")` with the different links for each placeholder's action.

Comment: @YelizavetaYR - actually, your other question was a little different - the `«Expr»[UserEmail]«Expr»[AgreementStatementPage]«Expr»` was correct. You'd just need to use an IIF in each of the `<<expr>>`. `=IIF(balance>0, "you owe blahblah", "No bal send to ")` and then the email placeholder and link.